# How can I install Docker Compose on a Windows Server 2019 box that has Docker Enterprise Edition (EE) installed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to install a Bitwarden self-hosted solution. The instructions here say that I need to install both Docker and Docker Compose.

How can I install Docker Compose on Windows Server 2019? I don't want to have to install Docker Desktop, which uses Docker Community Edition (CE).

Answer (score 2):

I am also using windows server 2019, so from the above page I used:

Invoke-WebRequest "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\docker-compose.exe

It workded perfectly okay for me

Answer (score 1):

Do you install docker with docker provider and package on Windows?

In PowerShell, run the following command to download Docker Compose, replacing $dockerComposeVersion with the specific version of Compose you want to use:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$dockerComposeVersion/docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $Env:ProgramFiles\docker\docker-compose.exe
```

You can see releases in https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

More details:
https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/compose/install/#install-compose

Answer (score 0):

powersheel command for docker-compose installation try this

Invoke-WebRequest "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.12.0/docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $Env:ProgramFiles\docker\docker-compose.exe